# D3D11 MultisampleEnable and AntialiasedLineEnable affecting line rendering

Tags: antialiasing, directx11, direct3d

Microsoft D3D11 [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ns-d3d11-d3d11_rasterizer_desc#remarks) for **D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC** structure writes:

> The settings of the MultisampleEnable and AntialiasedLineEnable members apply only to multisample antialiasing (MSAA) render targets (that is, render targets with sample counts greater than 1).

Should I expect line rendering to be affected by those members only when I am rendering to a multisampled target and not when I am rendering on a "single sampled" one?

When drawing a Line Strip I found line rasterization to be affected by those settings:

[image]

What am I missing?